# Angular service is referenced but not called, yet still "returns" correct value

Tags: angular, this, angular-services, angular-components

[In this Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/MBEGkqnV5kie9PB3az9K?p=preview), I've made a minor modification to the Angular.io tutorial.

I've added a function to the heroes.service called `doHeroesExist`. 
However, I never call it. The only thing I do it assign it to a variable in the `app.component`

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    //this.getHeroes();
    this.heroesExist = this.heroService.doHeroesExist;
    console.log("app ngOnInit called...", this.heroesExist);  // outputs: app ngOnInit called... true
  }
```

And here is the `doHeroesExist` function inside the `hero.service.ts` file.

```
  doHeroesExist(): boolean {
    console.log("doHeroesExist called..", this.doHeroesExist);
    return this.doHeroesExist;
  }
```

I am puzzled.

Why does it say **true** in the console log? Shouldn't it output the body of the function as string? Also the console.log inside the `doHeroesExist` is never printed - further proof it's not called!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT :

You forgot to mention that you had that defined in your service:

```
  doHeroesExist: boolean; 

  constructor() {
    this.doHeroesExist = true;
  }
```

not a good idea to have a member method and a member field with the same name...

Whatever is the definition of `doHeroesExist` was (function, other variable...) , in your constructor you just assign it the value of `true`. So it becomes a `boolean` with the value `true`.

That's it. I am surprised it compiles due to the name clash, but in any case the behaviour is clearly caused by your constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer and pointing out those issues. I realize now that I actually botched my question. I've made some changes and re-asked it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46657227/angular-giving-a-component-field-a-reference-to-a-service-function-and-calling