# Angular: Giving a component field a reference to a service function and calling it from template not working as expected

Tags: angular, this, angular-services, angular-components

[In my Plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/MBEGkqnV5kie9PB3az9K?p=preview) (modified [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial) app from official docs) I created this method in the `hero.service`

```
  doHeroesExist(): boolean {
   console.log("doHeroesExist called..", this.heroesExist);
   alert("doHeroesExist called.." + JSON.stringify(this.heroesExist));
    return this.heroesExist;
  }
```

and use it in the `app.component` class

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    //this.getHeroes();
    this.heroesExist = this.heroService.doHeroesExist;
    console.log("app ngOnInit called...", this.heroesExist);
```

}

as call the `heroesExist()` method in the template

```
<button (click)="heroesExist()">Do Heroes Exist?</button>
```

**I am puzzled by its behaviour.**

When I click the <kbd>Do Heroes Exist?</kbd> button, I expect the console (and alert popup) to log **"doHeroesExist called.. true"**, but instead it logs the entire body of the service function:

> doHeroesExist called.. ƒ () {
>           console.log("doHeroesExist called..", this.heroesExist);
>           alert("doHeroesExist called.." + JSON.stringify(this.heroesExist));
>           return this.heroesExist;
>       }

Why is this happening?

Why doesn't the service correctly evaluate `heroesExist = true;` as it is defined in the service's constructor?

PLUNKER LINK: https://plnkr.co/edit/MBEGkqnV5kie9PB3az9K?p=preview

Comment: You're treating the `this.heroService.doHeroesExist` like a property, rather than calling it like a function `this.heroService.doHeroesExist()`. Missing parens on the end. Is that what you really need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass the function around and call it later in another context, the context of `this` in the function is lost. That's why you see the alert showing "doHeroesExist called.. undefined", as `this` in your service method isn't referring to the service itself.

To solve it, before returning the function as a variable, bind the context to it:

```
this.heroesExist = this.heroService.doHeroesExist.bind(this.heroService);
```

Comment: Oh I thought Typescript took care of those issues . Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Well IMO it's not an issue to be fixed. Typescript introduces another way to tackle that, the fat arrow function. You'll have the same result if you use this `this.heroesExist = () => this.heroService.doHeroesExist();`

Answer (score 1):

In ur plunker just replace  `<button (click)="heroesExist()">Do Heroes Exist?</button>`

with

```
 <button (click)="heroService.doHeroesExist()">Do Heroes Exist?</button>
```

That worked for me

Comment: That's cool. I didn't think of it. I've been creating pass-through functions in the components

Comment: It seems though I'll have to make a `heroService` a public field of the `app.component`