# How does one store constants in Angular 2+?

Tags: angular, angular-services, shared-variable

This is a follow-up question to [an earlier question I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46657227/angular-giving-a-component-field-a-reference-to-a-service-function-and-calling/46657303?noredirect=1#comment80264302_46657303).

My question there was about strange log output I was getting when calling a method on a service. The `console.log` output was not printing the data that the service clearly defined. The culprit as it turns out was that when calling the service method, the context that is used is the context of the component making the call.

**So my question is**: What is the proper way to store variables across multiple components in Angular 2+?

For example, say I wanted to keep a variable `isLoggedIn`. Where do I keep this variable? I cannot keep it in a service because when components call that service (i.e. `authService.getLoggedInStatus()`) they will not neceesarily get the `isLoggedIn` value of the service, but rather, potentially, of an identically named variable in the component.

So how do you keep track of shared variables in Angular?

Comment: Why would "authService.getLoggedInStatus()" give the value of identically named variable in the component? This is a valid way. @Injectables are singleton and good for storing values.

Comment: I personally, used this very exact approach on one of my project to store logged in user data with `BehaviourSubject` in a `Service` called by all login required `components`; and it works perfectly fine. Plus it gives an advantage of if everything is `subscribes` to one service, when it changes, all components would know the change. I.E Logout is automatically registered by all `subscribe`rs

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to keep a global variable `isLoggedIn` accessable anywhere in the application, placing it in a `@Injectable service` as a [singleton](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/singleton) service is completely valid. In order to make sure it is singleton service you should only declare it in app.modules e.g

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SingletonService } from './Singleton.service';

@NgModule({
 declarations: [
    AppComponent,
 ],
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
 ],
 providers: [SingletonService],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

If you also add it in the components via so:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
  providers: [SingletonService]
})
```

You initialize a new Service instance, and your intended global `isLoggedIn` would have it's own instance in this component.

Hope this give you some sense of how to store global variables using `@Injectable()` in angular.

More information on Dependency Injection [here.](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/di/)

Answer (score 0):

@Injectable services are singleton. You provide this service on the relevant module that the components are declared upon. Via dependency injection of this service in subject components you can access its public properties. Thus, you can share these properties and their values